# How to get a real time within PostgreSQL transaction?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transactions

As far as I understand *now()* returns the same time during the whole PostgreSQL transaction?
But how to get **real** time?

Also, I am interested if there any configuration parameter to limit duration of transaction, so that after this period expiration transaction would immediately fail or somehow else prohibit following queries?

Comment: Those two questions seem unrelated to me.

Comment: I would like to limit transaction duration abuse, so, depending on the standard solution flexibility I would choose it, or my custom solution based on real time (fail transaction in stored procedure). So, questions are related in the scope of my task.

Comment: I can find no documentation on transaction duration / timeout with rollback. You might get something out of session timeouts (and fire this transaction in a dedicated session), but that's still not elegant. I'd see if your spiffy custom solution works. :)

Comment: See [documentation on Current Date/Time](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). Especially function `clock_timestamp` might be of use for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Timeofday()
```

May work for you.

Comment: A quirk you have to have in mind: "timeofday() is a historical PostgreSQL function. Like clock_timestamp(), it returns the actual current time, but as a formatted text string rather than a timestamp with time zone value."

Comment: @Milen Thanks for your comment. It should be an answer by itself so I can upvote it :)

Comment: @MilenA.Radev `timeofday()` indeed returns a text, but `clock_timestamp()` returns a timestamp with time zone.

Answer (score 117):

Use `clock_timestamp()`.

`now()` is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to `transaction_timestamp()`, which is equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. These functions return the start time of the current transaction. Their values do not change during the transaction.

`statement_timestamp()` returns the time of receipt of the latest command message from the client.

`clock_timestamp()` returns the actual current time, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL command.

For more information see the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

Comment: Works for me, with a `TIMESTAMPTZ` column.

Answer (score -3):

To limit the time of a statement (not a transaction) you can use statement_timeout. now() will increment on each execution *if* not within a transaction block. Thus:

```
postgres=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2010-08-11 13:44:36.207614-07
(1 row)

postgres=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2010-08-11 13:44:36.688054-07
(1 row)

postgres=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2010-08-11 13:44:40.407623-07
(1 row)

postgres=# begin;
BEGIN
postgres=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2010-08-11 13:44:43.417611-07
(1 row)

postgres=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2010-08-11 13:44:43.417611-07
(1 row)

postgres=#
```