# Mystical postgresql query timing issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-16

I'm trying to log events in postgresql using this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE admin.log_event(
    IN log_message character varying,
    IN param1 character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    IN param2 character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
  declare ts timestamp;
  begin
    ts = now();
    insert into admin.event_log (dt, msg, param_1, param_2) values (ts, log_message, param1, param2);
  end;
$BODY$;
```

The usage pattern is:

- log event
- run query for several minutes
- log event
- ...

What I'm seeing in the event_log table is that all 24 entries for a query batch that lasted 35 minutes record the same timestamp, which is the time the batch was started.

Obviously I don't understand something about postgresql insert statements as I was expecting each row to reflect the timestamp for it's insertion into the request_log table.

Comment: Read [Current date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). I'm guessing you want `clock_timestamp()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [now() default values are all showing same timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216802/now-default-values-are-all-showing-same-timestamp), [now date function returns same result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513991/now-date-function-returns-same-result/), [How to get a real time within PostgreSQL transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363376/how-to-get-a-real-time-within-postgresql-transaction) or [Postgres now() timestamp doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512172/postgres-now-timestamp-doesnt-change)

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the `now()` [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> These SQL-standard functions all return values based on the start time
> of the current transaction:

So if you do an insert as part of a single transaction, they'll all get the same timestamp.

The library you use to connect to Postgres can have surprising transaction patterns.  For example, Python's psycopg2 [implicitly starts](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit) a transaction whenever you run an `insert` statement.

Comment: Each of the calls to log_event are separated by several minutes.  Maybe I need to do a commit in each call to log_event?

Comment: @HankBrandenburg. No you need to use the correct time function, `clock_timestamp()`. Then you don't have to worry about transactions.

Comment: A transaction groups multiple queries and guarantees atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability, aka [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).  An insert in a logging table is usually committed right away. Many client libraries have an autocommit function to do just that.